# can I develop a node module as GIT submodule

Tags: git, github, npm, node-modules

I have created a GIT Repo and I am going to develop  few node modules there.

So I started with my first node module(modA). and created a folder (submodule)  under it.

```
 https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/modA
```

I added a simple REAME there.

Now In my local machine I went to a project/node_module, and run this command.

```
 git clone 'https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/modA
```

I get this error

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/enraiser/node/enMailer/' not found'
```

I tried  **git submodule add**  but that also failed.

So my question is. whether all node plugin must be repository only?. or am I not using the proper GIT command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have created a folder inside your repository. It is not a submodule.
So your repo url is `git@github.com:enraiser/node.git` (using SSH) or `https://github.com/enraiser/node.git` (using HTTPS).

If you want to create your node modules as git submodules of your main repository, then you need
first to create separate repository for each module and then add them as submodules using their urls.

Assuming you already created enMailer repo and you have `<enMailer-url>`:

```
cd /local/path/to/your/repo
git clone git@github.com:enraiser/node.git .
rm -rf enMailer
git submodule add <enMailer-url> enMailer 
git add .
git commit -m 'submodule enMailer added'
git push origin master
```

**P.S.** Here is screenshot for you (where you can get correct repository url on github):
[image: Where to get correct repository url on github]

Comment: thanks, for explaining submodule.  I guess at list I am able to move forward.

Comment: Any comments from NPM perspective. Why I can make  node module as folder in GIT?

Comment: @enRaiser not sure if i understand you correctly... whether you need to create git submodules or not? If you want your modules to be accessible separately for installation via `npm` then yes, they shuold be each in own repository. Then you can install them this way: `npm install <module-url>`

Comment: I think subfolder is still better then submodule. but if there is any trick from NPM. Otherwise as you said I have to go for submodule.

Comment: @enRaiser other question is why do you need this common repository containing your node modules as git submodules?

Comment: because I want my visiter to look them collectively. rather then separate URLs.   and probably because a new repo just for small work does not make sense.

Comment: @enRaiser it is make sense (to create repo is not such a big deal). As i can see the main purpose of your common repo is just to describe your set of modules, and provide instructions to end-user. So here "big deal" is to keep links to your modules here as git submodules. You can just use README.md for this. The main purpose of git submodules is to include other repo as part of project and to be able to do version management with it (checkout to revision, or update for latest stable version for example) -- are you really need this here?